# Mootools ajax call removes data containing an empty array

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools, http-post

in my data object for the  ajax call, i've got something like this:

```
data: {
    someVariable: []
}
```

and when I start the ajax call, I can see in the POST data that `someVariable` is not being sent.

1. is this a mootools problem, or is it JS-wide?
2. how can i intentionally send an empty array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking through a reported bug in the jquery bug tracker, they said the following:

> The problem is that there is no way to serialize an empty array in a
>   way that makes sense in the x-www-form-urlencoded format. foo[bar]=
>   could either mean empty array, empty string, empty object, or
>   null/undefined value, depending upon how the backend chooses to
>   interpret it. Since neither way of serialization is really “correct”,
>   and most backends interpret this as “empty string”, and this breaks
>   traditional mode in quite a bad way (as per the forum thread), I’m
>   marking this to block 1.6 so it can be reverted back to the old
>   behaviour.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6481#comment:12

Therefore,

1. it is a limitation of javascript
2. no. what you can do is make a placeholder for an empty array where it is wrapped in quotes, like `'[]'` and on the server side, you can interpret that as a new empty array.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can send an empty array through an ajax call. You will need to come up with your own solution such as passing in array with an empty string[''] and handling that special case on the server side.